# Is it possible to experimentally reproduce the probability of type 1 errors in significance tests?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, inference, type-i-and-ii-errors, boxplot

In some fields, a lot of sample studies feature statistical tests. Oftentimes, box plots of sample distributions are shown.

I was wondering whether i could read distributional parameters from these plots and then generate additional samples from the same population (assuming normal distributions).I understand I am not actually sampling the same population as done in such a study. 
Still, I assume the best case for such a study would be to get a sampled distribution with identical parameters as the original population.

In order to reproduce the probability of type 1 errors for statistical tests done on the boxplotted data, I would generate samples of equal sample size repeatedly and perform significance tests on them.
My question is if this approach is valid to estimate the probability of type 1 errors.

1. Is it possible (and statistically valid) to recreate random variables or their distribution of a sample using a boxplot of said sample (assuming normal distribution)?
2. If the answer to 1. is yes, are there other distributions for which this approach is possible?
3. Is the best case for a sample study to have a sample with equivalent distribution parameters as the population sampled from?
4. Can the probability of type 1 errors significance tests be reproduced by performing analysis on generated samples based on question 1?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "probability of error" here. Which error are you talking about?

Comment: thank you for your comment! I am referring to type 1 errors. I'll edit the question to include this information.

Comment: To find the type I error rate you need work with the null being true; you don't know it's true in the data.

Comment: what if i assume the sampling distribution is equal to the true distribution?